# latency problems with wordpress install (from SQL import)

Tags: mysql, import, sql

I develop wordpress sites for a living, and today I am experiencing something that I haven't yet come across: Extremely slow load times / latency problems. You can view the site here: http://ziprecords.com.previewdns.com/  Here are the steps I took:

1. Developed a theme on localhost, everything worked perfectly.
2. Exported data from within wordpress backend
3. Opened up Godaddy account and set up new shared hosting account, and installed Wordpress using their self-installer. I am testing this site using their 'preview DNS', which enables you to view the site live before connecting a domain. Godaddy assured me, this works fine with WP installs.
4. I then attempted to import the data from the local install. There was errors on the media uploads (failed to import media).
5. I manually uploaded media files, and relinked the pictures to all my posts (from this point on, I knew something was fishy)
6. I went to my local phpMyAdmin and exported the entire database in SQL. (keep in mind, I am using a plugin called shopp, which powers the ecommerce section of the site. These tables were included in the export)
7. In a text editor, I replaced all of the local host references to the new domain URL.
8. I went to my Godaddy phpMyAdmin and dropped all of the pre-existing wordpress tables. I then imported the SQL database.
9. I then went to the site and looked at it. It was pretty darn slow.
10. It seemed like as I entered more products into the shop and more content on the site, it became slower and slower, but perhaps that is a coincidental. I am experiencing some SEVERE latency/speed problems.
11. I called Godaddy, and after some tests, they said everything is fine on their end.
12. I then tried testing this out on ANOTHER server using the exact sames steps as above. When I tried uploading the XML backup, EVERYTHING failed to import, even post types and post content. When I tried importing the SQL, everything works fine. The new site is working as I wish as far as speed, however, all of the content is completely missing, due to the failed import.

So now I am stuck in a situation where I am unable to target the cause of this problem, and I don't have a working test environment because the Wordpress import fails every time.

The latency problems could be on Godaddys end; however, I am sure that something is screwed on on the WP DB, as indicated by the failed media imports/ exports, as well as the extremely slow latency.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have another server you can test on? Follow the same process and see whether you get the same problems. That will at least show whether GoDaddy is the problem

Comment: Good idea, I will do that, but I am almost positive, it is on my end, not godaddys.

Comment: everything failed to import when I tried importing all the content. There are some serious issues I suppose

Comment: On your other test server? What errors did you get? How big is the database? Can you update your question and detail what steps (actually add the commands you're using) you're performing?

Comment: sure, give me a moment

Comment: redid question to outline my steps

Comment: ***Opened up Godaddy account*** They are very well known for [MySQL latency problems](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=godaddy+slow+mysql).

Comment: It sure sounds like your issue is with the data. Is your old version of WP the same as the new version? When you try to import XML, you say it fails -- does it provide you with an error? Have you tried a plugin like blackbox to see if there are any errors happening, or if there are an excessive number of SQL queries happening? What's your permalink structure? Have you tried importing the SQL unaltered, and just changing the main domain in the options table (many links, images won't work, but that's OK for testing).

Answer (score 1):

Issues that I see in your description:

> installed Wordpress using their self-installer

It is commonly recommended to install WordPress by hand.

> In a text editor, I replaced all of the local host references to the new domain URL

This causes problems by breaking serialized data.

Comment: how do I go about addressing these issues?

Comment: @Jesse Chase first I think is self-explanatory - nuke site clean and install WordPress by hand with clean copy from official site. Second - you need specialized tool to run replace with, I have [this one](http://spectacu.la/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) bookmarked for example.

Comment: The only problem is that the site has TONS of content on it. Loads of pictures, featured images, products. This took weeks to input. Being as the wordpress import/export isn't working for me, I am really keen on working out a solution on this WP install. Any thoughts? Much appreciated

Comment: @Jesse Chase broken native import is strange, but I have nothing to suggest from information you provided :(

Comment: ok :( thanks anyways. The site seems to be working much better right now. I think once I connect the domain, a lot of these issues should conclude